# Stop restart OSMC on exit

Tags: osmc

When I leave OSMC on my RaspBMC installation, it automatically restarts OSMC. I only have some seconds time to press ESC to prevent an immediate restart.

I already tried to comment out the line

```
Restart = on-abort
```

in

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/mediacenter.service
```

But with no effect.

How can I achieve to stay on the console, when I exit OSMC?

Answer (score 0):

> ## Stopping Kodi
>
> Kodi can be stopped via the command line as follows:
>
> `sudo systemctl stop mediacenter`

Source: https://osmc.tv/wiki/general/starting-and-stopping-kodi/